# How can I clean a gwt CellList?

Tags: java, gwt

How can I clean a gwt CellList ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by "clean" you mean "clear". I believe, that can be done by providing empty `List` to [`replaceAllChildren()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#replaceAllChildren%28java.util.List,%20com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
SelectObject object = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
if(object != null) {
    selectionModel.setSelected(object , false);
}
setRowCount(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
cellList.setRowCount(0)
```